# quick.cart ,custom jquery serach ,when submitting search , populate with the same text submitted the form on the page i will be redirected

Tags: php, jquery, forms, search

I am using the quick.cart 5.1 template from opensolution , the basic functionality of the search form from quick.cart is to search the products from the site , and i adapted this jquery custom search http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/ to fit the quick.cart site 
in container.tpl the original search script was :

```
<!-- IF:START SEARCH-FORM -->
        <form method="post" action="$sLinkSearch" id="searchForm">
          <fieldset>
            <span><label for="$lang[search]">$lang[search]</label><input type="text" size="15" name="sPhrase" id="$lang[search]" value="$sPhrase" class="input" maxlength="100" /></span>
            <em><input type="submit" value="$lang[search] &raquo;" class="submit" /></em>
          </fieldset>
        </form><!-- IF:END SEARCH-FORM -->
```

And i changed it to :

```
<!-- IF:START SEARCH-FORM -->
        <form method="post" action="$sLinkSearch" id="searchForm2">
          <fieldset>
           <span>  <input id="s" type="text"  / &lt;
            <em><input type="submit" value="$lang[search] &raquo;" class="submit" /></em>
          </fieldset>
        </form><!-- IF:END SEARCH-FORM -->
```

In the page that will show search results (`$sLinkSearch`) i have enterd this :

```
<div id="resultsDiv"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

in script.js i've added `$('#searchForm').submit();` at the end to resubmit the search-form
all i need is a way to fill the same search form from the search-results page with the text i've just submitted so that the wanted results will show up
I-ve tried to change `<input id="s" type="text" />` into `<input id="s" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['terms'])?>" />` 
but in the search form will appear this message  : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected  in /home/vhosts/sunpower.eu5.org/core/libraries/tpl-parser.php(120) : eval()'d code on line 1
 and it will not function corectly .
Is there any alternative to populate the next search form with the last text submitted , without using php ?
By the way , the website with the search-form mentioned is http://www.sunpower.eu5.org